# How does Symfony include classes when we invoke use with the class namespace?

Tags: php, symfony

How does Symfony know what classes to include when we put `use some_namespace`. Does it needs to include the file somewhere previously or it does it when we invoke the `use` statement — for instance, I have my file `product.php`:

```
namespace Facebook\Bundle\FacebookBundle\Domain;

class Product{
    //some codes
}
```

Then in the default controller

```
use Facebook\Bundle\FacebookBundle\Domain\Product;
```

Does the `use` statement find the file and include it?

Comment: I'd imagine the namespace maps to a filesystem path.  That's how it works in most frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony2 uses the standard [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). In short: it defines how classnames must map to filesystem paths. For example, in case of your example:

```
use Facebook\Bundle\FacebookBundle\Domain\Product;
//loaded from /path/to/project/Facebook\Bundle\FacebookBundle\Domain\Product.php
```

Behind the curtain Symfony has an autoloader - whenever you're trying to use a class that hasn't been defined yet, it translates the class name to a path and includes it, so you won't need to add any require statements to the top of your files.